# Sliding Window Maximum wrong answer

Tags: python, data-structures, sliding-window

#### Problem

> You are given an array of integers `nums`, there is a sliding window
> of size `k` which is moving from the very left of the array to the
> very right. You can only see the `k` numbers in the window. Each time
> the sliding window moves right by one position. Return the `max sliding window`.

[239. Sliding Window Maximum](https://leetcode.com/problems/sliding-window-maximum/description/)

#### Logic

I have a `maxSoFar` that constantly updates itself over every new `nums[j]` it encounters. Also, I have `secondMaxSoFar` which updates `maxSoFar` incase the `maxSoFar` is going out the window when we slide forward.

#### Code

```
class Solution(object):
    def maxSlidingWindow(self, nums, k):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type k: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        maxSoFar = float("-inf")
        secondMaxSoFar = float("-inf")
        toReturn = list()
        i = j = 0
        N = len(nums)

        while j < N:
            if nums[j] > maxSoFar:
                secondMaxSoFar = maxSoFar
                maxSoFar = nums[j]
            if nums[j] > secondMaxSoFar and nums[j] < maxSoFar:
                secondMaxSoFar = nums[j]
            if j >= k - 1:
                toReturn.append(maxSoFar)
                if nums[i] == maxSoFar and maxSoFar not in nums[i + 1:j + 1]:
                    maxSoFar = secondMaxSoFar
                    secondMaxSoFar = nums[j]

                i += 1
            j += 1
        return toReturn


solution = Solution()
a = solution.maxSlidingWindow([1, 3, -1, -3, 5, 3, 6, 7], 3)  # expected [3,3,5,5,6,7]
print(a)
a = solution.maxSlidingWindow([1], 1)  # expected [1]
print(a)
a = solution.maxSlidingWindow([1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 5], 3)  # expected [3,3,2,5]
print(a)
a = solution.maxSlidingWindow([-7, -8, 7, 5, 7, 1, 6, 0], 4)  # expected [7,7,7,7,7]
print(a)
a = solution.maxSlidingWindow([9, 10, 9, -7, -4, -8, 2, -6], 5)  # expected [10,10,9,2]
print(a)
a = solution.maxSlidingWindow([7157,9172,7262,-9146,3087,5117,4046,7726,-1071,6011,5444,-48,-1385,-7328,3255,1600,586,-5160,-371,-5978,9837,3255,-6137,8587,-3403,9775,260,6016,9797,3371,2395,6851,2349,-7019,9318,1211,-3110,8735,-7507,1784,7400,-5799,3169,-7696,-8991,-2222,-9434,-4490,4034,-831,-9656,5488,-4395,9339,4104,-9058,-4072,-1172,1758,6878,-5570,-6380,9550,-9389,1411,2298,3516,551,9196,5215,-237,-4146,1682,4418,-4639,7759,9593,-9588,3041,9208,-7331,-797,-2529,7738,-2944,4351,5091,-9448,-5404,6200,-1425,-3983,678,8456,-8085,5162,7165,4692,-494,-9249,8514,521,-8835,6745,-5775,-575,1876,-5464,5053,5567,3456,5873,1965,4316,2126,9462,-59,6544,-1547,7015,-8928,-3903,-3020,5865,-9479,6723,9214,5705,5136,7725,945,-1995,-2288,4579,7103,9938,4495,-730,-3180,7717,6824,794,-894,-1439,-1641,-4577,9362,-8817,-6035,-7980,-1278,-1928,-5390,-2342,1189,-2340,4788,-1814,5927,3115,9017,6801,7884,-5719,5992,7477,-486,-2734,-1557,3169,5288,-8295,-5651,2491,-3394,8302,-8822,5638,7654,7350,9884,-5392,881,-4874,5582,8309,-8514,2682,-6081,5602,4963,3538,9558,-6401,-2641,6223,-7107,-2772,5873,78,-7934,-7641,7872,7901,7436,-3815,-1540,-3387,3558,-8030,-6637,9609,8594,83,7984,-3286,7211,5877,-8655,6700,9855,-7521,903,1024,4051,4044,4044,8650,-2932,-134,-8167,-5338,-1014,391,1913,-9914,-9100,7108,-9250,1705,5615,641,6809,6619,7782,9062,3030,603,-2528,-5493,-1237,8428,1231,6701,202,641,-5351,-5366,-3347,7659,-3953,5518,1575,-3514,999,-6631,-934,-1119,1749,-9533,-8528,-9425,-9138,-6498,-1546,-8501,7668,-8135,-6234,7236,1722,-7690,7339,-5205,698,3680,7741,-9067,8739,-7658,-2518,3967,-128,620,-4571,780,5989,-6220,-1932,6629,-733,-6978,-68,-3295,9075,-297,7648,-7645,2301,-4641,-8443,6935,-6257,7067,-9046,5474,6833,6924,8516,-213,-9210,-9605,-5798,4710,-9258,-7736,944,5194,-7465,5978,-6840,3735,4392,9218,-5571,2944,-5864,2995,-5234,5036,-4999,-9883,5493,4646,9574,3528,291,-4799,-3099,7639,5144,-2560,-7573,433,2464,-3484,4673,3283,-6459,-1194,8122,7314,-3389,-1899,8362,-1046,-1751,-2140,7642,-6274,-8056,3925,-397,1641,5762,8099,-9683,2533,1333,3295,7413,-8538,-8585,8412,1958,-8487,7248,4987,-6079,9427,-6207,-7873,688,224,6792,-4150,3345,826,1885,6463,-5269,3068,9649,-1354,3159,4975,514,-3071,-4355,-1615,9427,8343,978,7914,-1876,1160,-898,-8431,6245,8760,8514,9857,9505,-3602,-4124,-4124,209,855,-253,-7232,-7598,6813,-565,-8739,2886,3289,-4339,7846,-3820,3001,-3235,-3146,-2535,-1444,8976,-8434,8190,-4185,5847,-1020,-6020,-3935,-4267,2030,6882,-7707,-5213,5284,-2061,-325,2911,2346,1080,-2111,-4929,-9101,1548,-4817,-7526,2688,-3589,-4414,6269,-1423,-6735,-7204,-6624,-7561,7775,-2650,-6843,735,3824,4592,-5199,-1922,1757,5662,-1272,4208,400,2883,720,9179,1056,3310,-7095,-3834,-2683,4422,-2599,-6124,1449,-5001,-5874,-7396,9158,2926,4281,-9423,8492,-1542,1197,6023,-9627,4970,28,7002,5204,5292,3901,4640,2994,-4487,-2102,-4481,-5347,1164,6773,6277,5759,-4250,-3920,4843,7763,-791,8478,-7750,7243,-4640,6252,8699,2001,9799,-5555,-3183,-6124,4787,1378,-4618,3349,-5561,-2392,-1764,9774,-5698,1775,-9616,-6353,-3622,-4907,1356,5728,-1902,-3203,5268,4414,1096,-1268,-940,179,-7824,9845,6093,9096,-163,3713,-297,6100,6544,6167,6209,-5476,4519,6391,289,1823,7256,5528,9069,-4861,2571,-5339,2657,-1383,-3771,-4709,-1915,-8712,-816,2266,-8078,-2451,-6189,-5910,-8027,4915,-5900,-2979,2028,4015,-2885,8665,3121,8692,-2479,-2824,-5047,-3116,-5621,-7248,-1462,1114,-907,5481,6605,8767,-506,3412,-7848,7333,-634,3219,-3273,3031,-1867,1765,1522,-7747,-7195,-9110,6320,-3756,5207,1190,6370,-3143,6745,-2833,1926,-985,-3126,-9019,9744,-9202,8817,-3722,-2002,8111,4457,4973,4275,7125,3828,-3613,-3104,6544,6764,6585,-4240,-3961,-2756,-5445,-1143,-9788,-6964,3690,-1158,-6795,9726,7048,8414,-4774,8405,-8837,3163,-9265,877,-6371,-5901,5427,243,-8247,-2653,-2356,-1228,-3403,-9628,4430,1937,-8435,3876,-9615,-1366,-8793,2136,496,3957,-1316,822,7134,-8320,-8789,-33,1803,-2617,4625,-4334,-46,6870,-9895,-3381,-6536,7742,6356,-1725,2283,-2267,532,-3571,4288,-40,4714,2145,-8173,-9782,-2821,8418,7097,-7187,-2945,830,-1110,7886,-821,-3453,-4313,-7945,7020,-2473,-4510,4867,-1992,3770,1031,6714,9721,-1399,-5297,-3545,-767,-2432,-8088,-6801,1689,7271,673,9178,7565,8263,-213,6693,843,940,9793,7536,-1742,266,9280,-402,8335,5091,-3019,-3904,-6956,-7393,1053,9830,-403,6191,7652,-5990,-7726,741,-7996,-3664,-5601,9598,6603,3714,8336,5228,-3757,7069,-371,-9984,2625,-5485,-14,8394,7757,4705,-5743,-3141,6589,8246,7689,5709,9201,9740,-5969,-3092,-5806,-1012,-7508,-9508,-9229,-6246,-5063,-8889,-4678,-7761,-4711,3076,-2699,224], 45)
# expected [9837,9837,9837,9837,9837,9837,9837,9837,9837,9837,9837,9837,9837,9837,9837,9837,9837,9837,9837,9837,9837,9797,9797,9797,9797,9797,9797,9797,9797,9550,9550,9550,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9593,9462,9462,9462,9462,9462,9462,9462,9462,9462,9462,9462,9462,9462,9462,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9938,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9884,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9855,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,9062,8739,8739,8739,8739,8739,8739,8739,8739,8739,8739,8739,8739,8739,8739,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9075,9218,9218,9218,9218,9218,9218,9218,9218,9218,9218,9218,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9574,9427,9427,9427,9427,9427,9427,9427,9427,9427,9427,9427,9427,9427,9649,9649,9649,9649,9649,9649,9649,9649,9649,9649,9649,9649,9649,9649,9649,9649,9649,9649,9649,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9857,9505,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8976,8190,8190,7775,7775,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9179,9158,9158,9158,9158,9158,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9799,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9845,9096,9096,9069,9069,9069,9069,9069,9069,9069,9069,9069,9069,9069,9069,9069,9069,9069,8767,8767,8767,8767,8767,8767,8767,8767,8767,8767,8767,8767,8767,8767,8767,8767,8767,8767,8767,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9744,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,9726,8414,8414,8405,8405,7742,7742,7742,7742,7742,7742,7742,7742,7742,8418,8418,8418,8418,8418,8418,8418,8418,8418,8418,8418,8418,8418,8418,8418,8418,8418,8418,8418,9721,9721,9721,9721,9721,9721,9721,9721,9721,9721,9721,9721,9721,9721,9721,9721,9721,9721,9793,9793,9793,9793,9793,9793,9793,9793,9793,9793,9793,9793,9793,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9830,9740,9740,9740,9740]
print(a)
```

#### Issue

As you can see it fails on the last test case. So far I have a suspicion on why it fails that I don't update `secondMaxSoFar` well, in case `nums[i] == secondMaxSoFar`. I am thinking maybe i keep a dict of the first second third maximum or maybe a priority queue? Maybe a priority queue that removes the `nums[i]` if we go out of the window (only if that is the max or secondMax). Before we jump to different data structures, I was hoping if there could be a solution in this one.

Comment: I guess there is no way to continously remember the maximum and second-to-maximum value in such an easy manner. Another failing example is `a = solution.maxSlidingWindow([4, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1], 4)` which returns `[5, 5, 4, 4]` because the code doesn't notice when `secondMaxSoFar` leaves the window and then sets `maxSoFar`wrongly. Simply searching the whole window for a new max when the old max leaves seems the best way to me.

Comment: I feel like k can be a function of n (n/2) size etc so wouldn't that make it O(n^2) level even if k is a constant per say

Comment: Did you notice that hint to this problem recommends "using a data structure such as deque",

Answer (score 0):

nums = [3255,1600,586,-5160,-371,-5978,9837]
k = 2

try this testcase for simplicity

The issue with your current code is that it doesn't handle the case where the maximum value is removed from the window and the second maximum value is not in the window either.